# How to stop React application from going back to home page on clicking save button?

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

I am developing an application using React/Redux. The application reads from a Json file and saves changes back to the json file.

Its a two page application but I am not using any router. All the editing and saving part is done on the second page, where I am hiding the home page.

My problem is that whenever I am saving something it goes back to the home page, which I know is the default behavior as the source is getting updated. So it is re-rendered. I am using different action for the second page rendering.

But what I am looking for is a simple solution for it to stay on the second page where I can show a success message that the data was saved.

Comment: Can you add the component codes ,seems like it has quick fixes?

Comment: The code is as follows -       render() {
    return (
      <section className="section">
        {!this.state.listView && (
          <div>
            <div className="connection-list default-margin-bottom ">
              <ConnectionsList ipLayer={ProtocolName} firstColumn />
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        {this.state.listView
        && (
        <ListView
          data={this.state.listConnectionData}
          onClick={this.handleConnectionListClick}
        />
        )}
      </section>
    );
  }

Answer (score 0):

"Where you are hiding the home page" - this suggests you are looking for clientside routing, for which react router would be the normal option: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router. You can also look into doing it purely with hooks: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-react-hooks-can-replace-react-router/